# Could not find any CSHTML or VBHTML views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, class-library, actionmailer.net

I'm using the ActionMailer.Net.Standalone package in a class library. In the root of the project I have a folder called "Templates" where I have my file OrderConfirmation.html.cshtml.

Like this:

[image]

Here is my mailer class:

```
public class Mailer : RazorMailerBase, IMailer
    {
        public RazorEmailResult OrderConfirmation(string toAddress, Order order)
        {
            To.Add(toAddress);
            From = "foo@bar.com";
            Subject = "Account Verification";
            return Email("OrderConfirmation", order);
        }

        public override string ViewPath
        {
            get { return "Templates"; }
        }
    }
```

When I run the project, I get the following error

`"Could not find any CSHTML or VBHTML views named [OrderConfirmation] in the path [Templates].  Ensure that you specify the format in the file name (ie: OrderConfirmation.txt.cshtml or OrderConfirmation.html.cshtml)"`

I'm guessing the path isn't correct. What path should I be using?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `Email("Temmplates/OrderConfirmation", order);` or `Email("/Temmplates/OrderConfirmation", order);`

Comment: and try the above suggestion with `public class MailController : MailerBase`

Comment: Did you solve this??? I had the same problem :(... My project is a little complicate since I'm doing it as web service

Comment: No I didn't. I'm using it directly in my MVC project for the time being. I was going to contact the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionMailer expects absolute path to ViewPath folder, i.e. in your case it should be like "c:\Mike\GreatProjects\eshop\Templates", not just relative "Templates".

Answer (score 0):

I went to my view properties: "Verification.txt.cshtml", and I changed `Build Action: Content`, and the `Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always`, like this:

[image]